# Issue using Graphql in my react app. I just can't get the variable section to work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, shopify

I am creating a Shopify app that takes in information from the user and creates a product from that information. I am using react-apollo and graphql. I got it working with just the product title, vendor and type, but it doesn't work when I try to add a price or any other variant information. So I believe the issue is in my graphql syntax, but I've tried everything I could research. Any suggestions as to why this might not be working is much appreciated.

```
const New_Product = gql`
      mutation {
        productCreate(input: {
          title: "${PartManufacturer} ${PartMake} ${ModelName}", 
          productType: "${PartType}", 
          vendor: "${this.state.Vendor}",

          variants: [{
            price: "${this.state.Price}",
            compareAtPrice: "${this.state.CompareAtPrice}",
            sku: "${this.state.SKU}",
            barcode: "${this.state.Barcode}",
            weight: "${this.state.Weight}"
          }]
        }) 
        {
          userErrors {
            field,
            message
          }
        }
      }
    `;

      return (
        <Mutation mutation={New_Product}>
          {(createProduct, { data }) => (
            <div>

                <button type="submit" onClick={createProduct}>Create Product</button>

            </div>
          )}
        </Mutation>
      );
```

Comment: test graphql in playground? how do you want to add many variants whis way? read docs

Comment: You should avoid using string interpolation and utilize variables instead. This allows you to pass in values as JSON that is then parsed into the appropriate types by the GraphQL server. Variable usage with Apollo is [shown in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/). Variable usage in general is explained [here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/).